# Starting a cancellable background task in a Service

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, handler

I want to start a background task, maybe a `Handler` or `Asynctask` inside of an `IntentService`. But I also need it to be `cancellable`.

In this background task I want to start a timer and after say 30 seconds I would like to execute a server call. But I would also like to be able to cancel the server call if the user presses a button in a `DialogFragment`.

Would starting `Post Delayed Handler` achieve this? If so, how do I access said `Handler` from my `Activity`?

Answer (score 0):

First have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html). 
 
As you will read, you can not stop a task running in a IntentService.

I will suggest to use a handler to star or not the Service. Let's say for example prupose that you have **Button A** and **Button B**. When you click Button A the app after 30 secs runs the task but meanwhile if you press Button B the Service will not be launched. 

 When Button A is pressed you can send a delayed message to the handler (delay of 30 sec) and if button b is pressed you can set a local variable to false and when handler finaly recives this message you can check the variable to see if to run the service or not